# N Queens with Haskell

Tags: haskell, n-queens

I tried to solve the N Queens problem in Haskell using backtracking. Here is my approach:

```
type Solution = [Int]

extend :: Solution -> Int -> Maybe Solution
extend b new = go 0 b
  where
    n = length b
    go _ []  =  Just (b ++ [new])
    go i (x:xs)
      | x == new                      = Nothing
      | abs (i - n) == abs (x - new)  = Nothing
      | otherwise                     = go (i+1) xs

fullExtend :: Int -> Solution -> Maybe Solution
fullExtend n partialSolution
  | length partialSolution == n     = Just partialSolution
  | otherwise                       = foldr propose Nothing [0..(n-1)]
  where
    propose _ (Just xs) = Just xs
    propose x Nothing   = extend partialSolution x >>= fullExtend n

nQueens :: Int -> Maybe Solution
nQueens n = fullExtend n []
```

Can the `propose` function be expressed in a more elegant way? I am only happy to get one solution here, and shortcircuiting the evaluation is fine.

I also experimented a bit more to find out all the solutions. Here is how I did so:

```
extend' :: Solution -> Int -> [Solution]
extend' b new = go 0 b
  where
    n = length b
    go _ []  =   [b ++ [new]]
    go i (x:xs)
      | x == new                      = []
      | abs (i - n) == abs (x - new)  = []
      | otherwise                     = go (i+1) xs

fullExtend' :: Int -> Solution -> [Solution]
fullExtend' n partialSolution
  | length partialSolution == n     = [partialSolution]
  | otherwise                       = [0..(n-1)] >>= (\x -> extend' partialSolution x >>= fullExtend' n)

nQueens' :: Int -> [Solution]
nQueens' n = fullExtend' n []
```

General comments on coding style would also be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**:

1. Don't repeat yourself. If you notice that code is very similar, ask whether you can use that similarity.
2. Express functions with other functions.
3. Avoid `length` in recursive calls, as it will add another factor `n` to your time complexity

Overall, still well done.

## Naming and (time) complexity

Let's start by looking at the types. Well, you have type signatures at every top-level binding, which is a great start. I think that the name `Solution` is slightly misleading, since you call the variable `b` for `Board`. But naming is hard, so let's focus on other parts.

```
extend :: Solution -> Int -> Maybe Solution
extend b new = go 0 b
  where
    n = length b                                       -- 1
    go _ []  =  Just (b ++ [new])                      -- 2
    go i (x:xs)
      | x == new                      = Nothing        
      | abs (i - n) == abs (x - new)  = Nothing        
      | otherwise                     = go (i+1) xs
```

`extend` has two small problems. First, `xs ++ [e]` (see `2` above) is linear (\$\mathcal O(n)\$), whereas `e : xs` is constant (\$\mathcal O(1)\$). If possible, we  should prefer the second variant. And `length b` is also linear (see `1` above). But if we fix `2` we don't need `n` anymore:

```
extend :: Solution -> Int -> Maybe Solution
extend bs new = go 1 bs
  where
    go _ [] = Just (new : bs)
    go i (x:xs)
      | x == new           = Nothing
      | i == abs (x - new) = Nothing
      | otherwise          = go (i + 1)
```

Note that I've renamed `b` to `bs`, since the suffix `s` indicates multiple elements.

## Don't repeat yourself

Although yout `extend` and `extend'` differ, the logic in `go` is almost the same. That's a sign that you can re-use the code, so let's try that:

```
placeable :: Int -> Solution -> Bool
placeable n xs = null [ x | (i,x) <- zip [1..] xs, x == n || abs (x - n) == i]
-- same as
placeable' :: Int -> Solution -> Bool
placeable' n xs = go 1 xs
  where
    go _ []     = True
    go i (x:xs) = x /= n && abs (x - n) == i && go (i + 1) xs
```

Now we can simplify `extend` and `extend'`:

```
extend :: Solution -> Int -> Maybe Solution
extend bs new = if placeable new bs 
                  then Just (new : bs) 
                  else Nothing

extend' :: Solution -> Int -> [Solution]
extend' bs new = if placeable new bs 
                   then [new : bs]
                   else []
```

Feel free to use guard syntax instead.

## Reuse functions

If you have a function `listToMaybe :: [a] -> Maybe a`, you don't need to write `extend`:

```
extend :: Solution-> Int -> Maybe Solution
extend bs new = listToMaybe (extend' bs new)
```

We can do the same for `nQueens` and get rid of `extend` completely:

```
nQueens :: Int -> Maybe Solution
nQueens n = listToMaybe (nQueens' n)
```

But you need to be lazy enough for that.

## Use knowledge you already have

In `fullExtend`, you'll check whether you already reached the correct length:

```
fullExtend :: Int -> Solution -> Maybe Solution
fullExtend n partialSolution
  | length partialSolution == n     = Just partialSolution             -- here
  ...
```

However, that's again \$\mathcal O(n)\$. But we know the length of our current solution; almost. It's the number of recursive calls:

```
  ...
    propose x Nothing   = extend partialSolution x >>= fullExtend n  -- one element more
```

Also `n` does not change. This calls for a `go`-like function:

```
fullExtend :: Int -> Solution -> Maybe Solution
fullExtend n = go n
  where
    go 0 partialSolution = Just partialSolution
    go k partialSolution = foldr propose Nothing [0..(n-1)]
      where
        propose _ (Just xs) = Just xs
        propose x Nothing   = extend partialSolution x >>= go (k - 1)
```

We now count down from `n` to `0` in `go`. Whenever we reached `0`, we have all `n` elements. This removes the need for `length`. At this point `fullExtend` is almost the same as `nQueens`, so we can get rid of it:

```
nQueens :: Int -> Maybe Solution
nQueens n = go n []
  where
    go 0 partialSolution = Just partialSolution
    go k partialSolution = foldr propose Nothing [0..(n-1)]
      where
        propose _ (Just xs) = Just xs
        propose x Nothing   = extend partialSolution x >>= go (k - 1)
```

We can use the same approach for `fullExtend'`. First, get rid of `length`:

```
fullExtend' :: Int -> Solution -> [Solution]
fullExtend' n partialSolution = go n partialSolution
  where
    go 0 xs = [xs]
    go k xs = [0..(n-1)] >>= (\x -> extend' partialSolution x >>= go (k - 1))
```

Then rewrite `nQueens'`:

```
nQueens' :: Int -> [Solution]
nQueens' n = go n []
  where
    go 0 xs = [xs]
    go k xs = [0..(n-1)] >>= (\x -> extend' xs x >>= go (k - 1))
```

By the way, this looks a little bit nicer with `do` notation:

```
nQueens' :: Int -> [Solution]
nQueens' n = go n []
  where
    go 0 bs = [bs]
    go k bs = do 
              x  <- [0..(n-1)]
              xs <- extend' bs x
              go (k - 1) xs
```

But that's up to you to decide.

## Your `propose` question

> Can the `propose` function be expressed in a more elegant way?

You can use `Maybe`'s `Alternative` instance:

```
propose x solution = solution <|> (extend partialSolution x >>= go (k  -1))
```

However, that's not really necessary if you rewrite `nQueens`

## All at once

If we also inline `extend`, we end up with the following code for the list variant:

```
import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)

type Board = [Int]

nQueens :: Int -> Maybe Board
nQueens = listToMaybe . nQueens'

nQueens' :: Int -> [Board]
nQueens' n = go n []
  where
    go 0 bs = [bs]
    go k bs = concatMap (go (k - 1)) [ x : bs | x <- [1..n], placeable x bs]

    placeable n xs = null [ i | (i,x) <- zip [1..] xs, n == x || abs (n - x) == i]
```

We could rewrite `go` above also as

```
    go k bs = do
              x <- [1..n]
              guard (placeable x bs)
              go (k - 1) (x : bs)
```

or

```
    go k bs = [1..n] >>= (\x -> guard (placeable x xs) >> go (k - 1) (x : bs)
```

but that's only personal preference, they all work the same.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from Zeta.

`placeable` disregards what's in the list that's checked for emptiness, unless:

```
placeable n xs = and [n /= x && abs (n - x) /= i | (i,x) <- zip [1..] xs]
```

`go` is a left fold and can be turned into a right fold for less argument passing.

```
go 0 = [[]]
go k = [x : bs | bs <- go (k - 1), x <- [1..n], placeable x bs]
```

This reveals that `iterate` can replace the explicit recursion:

```
nQueens' n = iterate (concatMap grow) [[]] !! n where
  grow bs = [x : bs | x <- [1..n], placeable x bs]
  placeable n xs = and [n /= x && abs (n - x) /= i | (i,x) <- zip [1..] xs]
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is really a ___review___ of the _original_ code.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by 

"disregards what's in the list that's checked for emptiness"?

Comment: One could write `null [ i | (i,x) <- zip [1..] xs, n == x || abs (n - x) == i]` as `null [ x | (i,x) <- zip [1..] xs, n == x || abs (n - x) == i]` or `null [ () | (i,x) <- zip [1..] xs, n == x || abs (n - x) == i]`